# How to hide group columns using toggler primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have on list with values ​​and i need to hide multiple columns.

The problem is when i hide my column using toggler, it hides only one column.

Corrects options:

option1: hide column "PA01", hide column "A" and "B".

option2: hide "Data" column, hide "Data" column.

option3: hide column "DMT feed",  hide column "DMIT feed".

The problem:

[Example 1: All columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr5XN.png)

[Example 2: Hide column "PA01"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz55C.png)

My code:

```
<p:columnToggler datasource="dtPlanoAnual" trigger="toggler" />

        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Data"></p:column>
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Alim DMT">
                </p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="PA01">
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Teor Cu % PA01" toggleable="false">
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Teor Zn % PA01" toggleable="false">
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText for="data" 
                value="#{planoAnual.data}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText for="alimDMT" 
                value="#{planoAnual.alimDMT}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText for="teorCuPercentPA01"
                value="#{planoAnual.teorCuPercentPA01}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText for="teorZnPercentPA01"
                value="#{planoAnual.teorZnPercentPA01}" />
        </p:column>
```

Comment: Open issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4582

Comment: Thanks for help!